# Use CodeIgniter 3 sessions outside of CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a application that I am migrating into CodeIgniter 3.0. Most of the application is still in a custom PHP framework. I am wondering how I can share the PHP sessions between the two so when a user logs in, his session data is the same for the custom framework and CodeIgniter parts of the app.

Currently, when I go into a CodeIgniter portion, it creates the session fine (using the 'files' driver), but when I go into a page of the custom framework, it creates a brand new session.

Comment: it will be better to avoid CI sessions and use native php file sessions that will be accessible to both apps.

Comment: I thought that was what CodeIgniter 3 was using. I know it is different than the older versions.

Comment: Try this `unserialize($_COOKIE['ci_session']);` that will give you the CI session cookie in your framework.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet but that would only give me the CodeIgniter data in the custom framework. I need it to go both ways.